# Reading element type in xml with java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, url, element

I have to read xml file from http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/code/employees.xml , but i dont know how to make results like this: 
Seagull-permanent
Robin-contract 
Crow-permanent 
I mean, i have no idea how to read Employee type.

Here is my code

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
        new Test().start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void start() throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL("http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/code/employees.xml");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
    NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Personnel");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < descNodes.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = descNodes.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent() + "-"
           +  eElement.getElementsByTagName("Employee").item(0).getTextContent());


        }}}

private Document parseXML(InputStream stream)
throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory objDocumentBuilderFactory = null;
    DocumentBuilder objDocumentBuilder = null;
    Document doc = null;
    try
    {
        objDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        objDocumentBuilder = objDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        doc = objDocumentBuilder.parse(stream);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }       

    return doc;
}
```

}

If someone can help me, i will really appreciate that.

Comment: the Employee is an element and that element node has attributes. You need to getAttribute() on the node. see below.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too deep in your code: You are extracting the wrong elements: You want the `Employee` nodes, but you are selecting the `Personnel`. Replacing

```
NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Personnel");
```

with

```
NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
```

should get you going.

You need to pick the type as Attribute from the employee node.

```
private void start() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/code/employees.xml");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());

    // here you fetch all the Employees
    NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < descNodes.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = descNodes.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            // the NAME element and the type attribute
            System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent() + "-"
                    + eElement.getAttribute("type"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code works good, but i still have problem how to get this parameter
[link](http://prntscr.com/af19f1).

Not sure how to replace this code eElement.getElementsByTagName("Employee type").item(0).getTextContent()
to get Employee types.